# form to mail in cakephp not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Thanks in advance,I am using cakephp2.8.5 version. Hai I have a user form to insert into database and when form is submit the data is added to the database but I am not able to send mail in cakephp.Is there any other configuration to send mail in cakephp .Please anyone help me.

```
My view.ctp code as below

<form role="form" name="add_userform" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="UserAddForm" action="/invl_exams/users/add"> 
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Username</label>  
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserUsername" maxlength="255" name="data[User][username]">   
                                            <!--<p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p> --> 
                                            <label id="UserUsername-error" class="error" for="UserUsername"></label> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group"> 
                                            <label>Password:</label>                                    
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPassword" name="data[User][password]">
                                            <label id="UserPassword-error" class="error" for="UserPassword"></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Full Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserFullName" maxlength="255" name="data[User][full_name]">
                                            <label id="UserFullName-error" class="error" for="UserFullName"></label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][email]">
                                            <label id="UserEmail-error" class="error" for="UserEmail"></label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Secondary Email</label>                             
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserSecEmail" maxlength="255" name="data[User][secondary_email]">
                                            <label id="UserSecEmail-error" class="error" for="UserSecEmail"></label>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Phone</label>                             
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="UserPhone" maxlength="255" name="data[User][phone]">
                                            <label id="UserPhone-error" class="error" for="UserPhone"></label>
                                          </div>
</form> 

Controller Page is UsersController.php
<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {


        if($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put'))
        { 

           $this->User->create(); 
           $this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);           
            $this->request->data['User']['docfile'] = $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name'];
             $file = $this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'];     

             move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/invl_exams/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']);    


               if($this->User->save($this->request->data))   
                { 

                //$this->Session->setFlash('<p style="width:220px;background-color:#34A853;color:white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">User is Created Successfully</p>');        
                // $this->redirect('index');

                  // To send mail after adding the user

                   $this->loadModel('User');                         
                   $user_name = $this->request->data['User']['username'];      
                   $password = $this->request->datadata['User']['password'];     

                    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');      
                    $email = new CakeEmail('smtp'); 
                    $email->to('ragith.thomas@gmail.com');     
                    $email->subject('test');              
                    $email->template("Use this link <a href='http://localhost/invl_exams/'> to login <br/>
                                      Your Username: ".$user_name." and Password:".$password); 
                    $email->emailFormat("html");     
                    $email->send();

                   // email ends here 


                  $this->redirect('addExam');                   


               } 



        }  

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not able to send"? `send()` function returns `false`, e-mail message is not delivered or do you see some error messages? Please add some detail.

Comment: I am getting error like this mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: In app/Config/email.php i have added public $smtp = array(
  'transport' => 'Smtp',  
  'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
  'port' => 465,
  'timeout' => 30, 
  'username' => 'ragith.thomas@gmail.com',   
  'password' => 'password',    
  'client' => null, 
  'tls' => false
  
 );

Comment: And is it working now? By setting `CakeMail('smtp')` you are defining `configuration` and it have to be correct. Do you have a reason to supply it?  Without configuration Cake uses default configuration what should be ok for you (if you have some SMTP server running on your box).

Comment: Now I am getting error like this, Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: How to configure PHP for this " ssl ". I am using WAMP server so how can in configure ssl

Comment: Please guide me I am not getting any solution for this

Comment: You have two choices a) remove `smtp` configuration when creating `CakeMail` object - it will use your local SMTP server (if any) or b) add `ssl` support to PHP to connect to GMAIL. Ad b) depends what OS you are running - Windows or Unix/Linux? Please provide more detail.

Comment: And did you try @Ayaou solution? It should work without ssl support in PHP.

Comment: I changed email.ctp public $smtp = array(
  'transport' => 'Smtp',
  'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'My Site'),  
  'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
  'port' => 465,
  'timeout' => 30, 
  'username' => 'ragith.thomas@gmail.com',   
  'password' => 'mypassword',    
  'client' => null,
  'tls' => false 
  //'log' => false, 
  //'charset' => 'utf-8',
  //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
 );

Comment: And in controller i have included smtp inside the cakeEmail() like this $email = new CakeEmail('smtp'); now i am getting error as : SMTP server did not accept the password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130378/discussion-between-user1315357-and-ragith-thomas).

Comment: See my answer, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

in your email file config, located at app/Config/email.php, add the following :

(Using gmail)

```
class EmailConfig {

    public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'youremail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'yourPassword',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => false // it's important to set tls to `false`
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow your app as "less secure app" at Google to access your account, please refer to for more information:

[Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

then use standard non-tls setting (tls is disabled in default) in `/app/Config/email.php`:

```
public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'from' => 'ragith.thomas@gmail.com',
        'username' => 'ragith.thomas@gmail.com',
        'password' => '{YOUR_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE}'
    );
```

and it will work.

Comment: Now the situation is there is no error but I am not able to receive any mail in my gmail account

Comment: What does it mean? You cannot login into Gmail web or you don't see any message in your folder? + try to checkout SPAM folder.

Comment: Very sorry, I am not able to find any mail in my Inbox as well as in Spam folder

Comment: Please try to Gmail help or Google search to search way how to solve this issue. But this is definitely not connected to your original question, it seems that your CakePHP app now sends an e-mail messages correctly. Please accept answer to your original question.

Comment: ya i do that , Thank you very much for your kind help